# How to plot events based on beginning and end of day in rechart

Tags: reactjs, graph, recharts

Hello I want to plot a graph on rechart library based on the data I have however I want it to be such that on the start of the x axis it labelled 12am (start of date) and end it is 11:59pm then using this I can plot a graph based on the events of the day

here is how my data looks like

```js
        const data=[{moneyIn: 100, time: '9:07 AM'}
 
        {moneyIn: 140, time: '9:07 AM'}
 
       {moneyIn: 250, time: '9:08 AM'}]
```

here is how I have plotted my current graph

```js
      <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" aspect={aspect}>
        <AreaChart
          width={730}
          height={300}
          data={data}
          style
          margin={{ top: 10, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
        >
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="total" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
              <stop offset="5%" stopColor={color} stopOpacity={0.8} />
              <stop offset="95%" stopColor={color} stopOpacity={0.3} />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <XAxis dataKey={time} stroke="gray" />
          <YAxis />
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" className="chartGrid" />
          <Tooltip />
          <Area
            type="monotone"
            dataKey={moneyIn}
            stroke={color}
            fillOpacity={1}
            fill="url(#total)"
          />
          </AreaChart>
          <ResponsiveContainer/>
```

this produces the folowing result

[image]

However i want the time to begin from 12am to 11:59pm then plot those points according to time, how do i do it? What other library can these be achieved in?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the axes to a given value by providing the `ticks` attribute:
[This thread](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/774) on the Recharts Git discusses how.

> <XAxis ticks={[1.2, 2.8, 4.4, 6]} />

You may want to have a few more ticks in your example, like 12-noon.
But you may have to format your x-axis values into a `number` or `date` value in order to make it work how you expect.

The XAxis Docs from [Recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis) give some good pointers on how certain props change the behaviour of the XAxis.